# Can a thin pole break or be cog-sensitive under the influence of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, pressure, free-body-diagram

[image]

When we consider such a phenomenon, what I am wondering is that the body of an object having a thin radius seems to cause the center post to be broken or the cog to be very sensitive, but why should I examine what issues?

I feel that the cog is very sensitive if I am holding a pen on my finger and the body is thin. tipping over

I'd love to see a relational equation on this.

Comment: You may check [Bending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending) and [Flexural rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_rigidity).